# Is it possible to add a feature to attach code-blocks to a post form?

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I've been trying to find something about this for a while, but I don't know if its my wording but I can't seem to find anything about it.

Anyways... I'm working on a project for school, and basically it's a website that does many things, and one of those things is like a *mini-stackoverflow* thing but just for my school's community. So I have designed a form for the post using *crispy forms* however I can't seem to find any information on how to add the feature to write in code blocks to a form **(just like we do here on Stack Overflow).**

This is what the form looks like on code:

**Template:**

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Nueva Publicación</legend>
                        {{ form|crispy }}
                    </fieldset>
                    <div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Crear Publicación</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

**Models**

```
class Post(models.Model):
titulo  = models.CharField(max_length=150)
contenido = models.TextField()
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
imagen = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='blog_images')

def __str__(self):
    return self.titulo

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("post-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

**Visually:**

[image: form_post]

If you guys need anything else in order to help, please tell me and I will provide ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a module that can translate Markdown-formatted text into HTML. It looks like [django-markdownx](https://neutronx.github.io/django-markdownx/) can do this for you.

- You can [add supported extensions to a list](https://neutronx.github.io/django-markdownx/customization/#markdownx_markdown_extensions).
- MarkdownX uses the python-markdown package, which has a [list of supported extensions](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/#officially-supported-extensions). You would add the *code fences* extension to your extension list.

Just follow the [Installation](https://neutronx.github.io/django-markdownx/installation/) and [Getting Started](https://neutronx.github.io/django-markdownx/getting_started/) directions, which I have summarized below.

First, install MarkdownX:

```bash
pip install django-markdownx
```

In `settings.py`, add it to your list of installed apps:

```python
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # [...]
    'markdownx',
)
```

In `urls.py`, add MarkdownX URLs:

```python
urlpatterns = [
    # [...]
    path('markdownx/', include('markdownx.urls')),
]
```

Make sure you have a `STATIC_ROOT` setting in `settings.py`. This line will create a `static` directory in the root folder of your project:

```python
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'
```

Add MarkdownX static assets to `STATIC_ROOT`:

```python
python3 manage.py collectstatic
```

Change `Post.contenido` to use `MarkdownxField`:

```python
from markdownx.models import MarkdownxField
from markdownx.utils import markdownify

class Post(models.Model):
    # title = ...
    contenido = MarkdownxField() # not models.TextField()
    # date_posted, author, etc.

    def formatted(self):
        "Returns formatted HTML for post content."
        return markdownify(self.contenido)
```

In your template, add `{{ form.media }}` after your `</form>` tag.

Now, your post content should appear with Markdown formatting whenever you use `{{ post.formatted|safe }}` in a template, like this:

```python
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h2>{{ object.title }}</h2>
{{ object.formatted|safe }}
{% endblock %}
```

*I tested this with Django 4.0.2, django-markdownx 3.0.1, and markdown 3.3.6.*